# Swat Kats: What is the origin of Dark Cat?

Tags: history-of, cartoon, swat-kats

In the short-lived [but kick @$$ *awesome!!!!* ] *Swat Kats: The Radical Squadron,* the titular heroes faced an **impressive** roster of villains, ranging from mad scientists [Dr. Viper] to undead sorcerers [The Past Master] to even mutants, robots, cyborgs and even aliens. Below is a general cast shot.

[image]

One of the major recurring antagonist was the abnormally tall, scientific genius known as Dark Kat. He *seemed* to be somewhat deformed, or possessed of some type of unnatural ability besides his scientific and criminal genius and extensive personal resources, inclusive of slowed aging. He was also accompanied/served by semi-intelligent, loyal winged minions called "creeplings".

[image]

However, unlike most of the other major villains, he was never [to my knowledge] given a back story in-show.

Is there any information on who Dark Kat is, why he seeks to take over Mega-Kat city, where the Creeplings came from and what his abilities are?